# Debug vs release modes on the iPhone

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0

Can anybody explain debug and release modes in the iPhone SDK? What is their importance and how are they distinguished?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Xcode / Cocoa : What are the differences between debug and release builds?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/761628/xcode-cocoa-what-are-the-differences-between-debug-and-release-builds)

Answer (score 2):

A debug mode is when the compiler keeps debugging information for use with the debugger. It also doesn't optimize the code, as optimizing can make debugging tricky.

Release mode takes out the debugging symbols and turns on optimization. It's generally done when "releasing" the product, since you want it to run as fast as possible.