# what's the difference between debug and release in xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, ios, xcodebuild

I just want to know what's the difference between building `iOS` application under `release` and under `debug` , becuase sometimes my code not work for `debug` and work for `release` , and vice versa

Comment: This question is a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/761628/xcode-cocoa-what-are-the-differences-between-debug-and-release-builds

Comment: possible duplicate of [Xcode / Cocoa : What are the differences between debug and release builds?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/761628/xcode-cocoa-what-are-the-differences-between-debug-and-release-builds)